# Erase root password before reselling computer

Tags: 16.04

I want to erase the root password I had set on my laptop, so that I can sell it.  I currently have Ubuntu 16.04.

I've tried following some instruction videos on YouTube but they didn't work.

How can I erase the root password on my system?

Comment: On Ubuntu `root` usually doesn't have a password. Your `root` has? Or do you mean the password you enter when you do `sudo something`? That's _your_ password then, not `root`'s. To be honest: I'd wipe the disk before selling the laptop. The buyer can always boot in emergency mode and then see your HDDs content, even if he doesn't know the pwd.

Comment: Anyway, for selling the laptop I would recommend wiping the whole disk. Your Ubuntu account password is probably the least important secret on that device (unless you use that same password for other things too).

Comment: I agree with the previous advice to wipe the drive. If the buyer wants Ubuntu, you can make a fresh installation afterwards.

Comment: I don't agree with the above 2 users: if the content of the harddisk is important always sell a system without the harddisk. If you do not care about the content ... wipe the disk and be done with it.

Comment: @Rinzwind Why? Do you think data can be recovered from a wiped drive? Or are you saying the OP should keep the drive so he still has access to the data?

Comment: Why would you erase the root password?  Unless the purchaser intends to do a new OS install, s/he'll need it to do ordinary administrative tasks.  Why not simply reset it to something generic?  If the user does want a new install, you're better off wiping the disk, as others have suggested.

Comment: @jamesqf Well, on Ubuntu you don't need the root password to do ordinary administrative tasks, all you need is a "`sudo`-enabled" account. But I am also curious about why Mafe wanted to erase the root password.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I am not really familiar with ubuntu. And i thought the admin account password is the root. :)

Comment: @marcelm https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: @Rinzwind Nothing in that link talks about recovering data from a wiped disk, only from disks with partial failures, or after a quick format (which is nothing like a full wipe).

Comment: @David Z: How do you create or modify a "sudo enabled" account without at some point invoking root?  And why would you want to, when for most purposes it's easier to just become root?

Comment: @jamesqf You could create it by e.g. running the Ubuntu installer. And you would want to do so precisely because when you're using Ubuntu, it's _not_ easier to become root (by other methods not involving `sudo`). What I mean is, it sounds like you're commenting under the assumption that the user can log in as root but cannot use `sudo`, whereas most neither of those things hold true for a typical Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @Mafe Yes, the root account is the admin account and the root password is the administrator password. But by default, the root account in Ubuntu has password login disabled, and the system is set up so that you don't actually need to enable it. (Plus, even if you changed that, someone with physical access to the hard drive can easily get around the requirement for the root password.) It's not clear to me, at least, what you expected to gain by erasing the root password when it's not needed in the first place. That's what I was curious about.

Comment: @David Z: I'll grant that my Ubuntu-specific knowledge is limited - if I wanted something that looked and acted like Windoze, I'd just use Windoze.  But having to continually type "sudo" in front of every command that you need root access for seems excessive. while silently invoking sudo seems dangerous, except in a few cases (such as my system shutdown command).

Comment: @jamesqf You can always `sudo -i` to get an interactive root shell that is similar to `su -`.

Comment: @PerlDuck: Sure, I could, but why complicate my life?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you are selling the laptop it is a much better idea to wipe the hard disk completely, so that nobody can see your private information.

1. Boot from an Ubuntu live CD or USB.
2. Launch **Disk** and delete all partitions on the laptop's hard drive.
3. To go **Format** and where it says erase, select "Overwrite existing data with zeroes (slow).
4. Wait up to a few hours.

There are even more secure ways to erase the hard drive but overwriting with zeroes is the minimum that you should do.

Comment: Couldn't agree with this more. Wipe the drive. If it is an `ssd` use the manufacturer's low level command. If the buyer has any computer sense, s/he would wipe it anyway once received.

Comment: While I agree that this is the real answer to the question when it comes to selling a laptop... It doesn't really answer how to change the password. I'm curious what the true method of changing the password is. Sometimes you it's easier to change the password then reinstall everything it took to make Ubuntu work in the first place especially if there were compatibility issues

Comment: Note that there won't be any OS left on the laptop afterwards - so the buyer will have to install one themselves.

Comment: Yes, or the seller could then proceed to put a fresh install of Ubuntu on there (as stated in a suggested edit by @Caleb which would have been better as a comment)

Answer (score 10):

To lock / erase the root pw

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

Comment: I found this doesn't erase the root password. A quick edit of /etc/shadow puts it back.

Comment: @Joshua Well, yes, editing `/etc/shadow` can restore the password, but someone who can edit `/etc/shadow` could just as well change the password to anything they want and effectively gain full root access that way. So I think you have to assume that, if your "adversary" has access to edit `/etc/shadow`, all hope is lost. Given that, this seems reasonably effective for the cases where you want to protect from someone who doesn't have such access.

Comment: @DavidZ: My understanding is he wants to destroy the password to prevent the buyer from learning it.

Comment: @Joshua /etc/shadow only stores password hashes though. It's practically impossible to recover the real password from the hash in there.

Comment: The hashing scheme used for any individual password in /etc/shadow could be one of a number of schemes supported by [crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_\(C\)) and if it was set more than a couple of years ago (eg you've upgraded through a few LTS releases) it may still be DES or MD5, both easy-to-bruteforce.  The newer default is a SHA-2 based scheme using many iterations which mitigates this.

Answer (score 6):

As already pointed out in both comments as well as [thomasrutter's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/992424/11751), **the below probably isn't what you actually want to do.** You're probably better off clearing the hard disk (by overwriting it in its entirety), or removing it and selling the laptop without the hard disk. **However,** to answer the question that you did ask...

---

To *erase* the password for a user account, including `root`, the correct (and portable; this should work on any Linux system with `sudo` configured and a GNU userland, which covers most modern desktop and server Linux distributions) way is to start a terminal and then

```
sudo passwd --delete root
```

Alternatively, use `-d` in place of `--delete` (they are synonymous).

This will set the password for the named account (in this case, `root`) as empty, effectively erasing it, *but will keep the user account and its files intact*. **Note that this allows logging in with the root account, trivially allowing full access to all files on the system.**

Never delete the `root` account or files owned by it, unless you know for a fact that it's safe to delete such files. The root account is not used by humans on modern versions of Ubuntu (I don't know if ancient ones did use it), but it's required for the system to function properly.

Comment: Might it be appropriate to move the last paragraph (containing "**the above probably isn't what you actually want to do**") to the beginning, so that it has the most chance of being heeded?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I think it is not the password I should be worried about :) i’d rather clear the hard disk :)

Comment: @LSpice Good idea. Done.

Comment: As far as I remember you may have to use `-d` and `-l`, else on some systems running `su` grants access without a password! See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo